# Buttons not working in JavaFX game of chance?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a simple game of chance in JavaFX where the user rolls a dice, guesses whether the next roll will be higher or lower, and bets points from a pool. However, I'm running into an issue where the buttons for rolling the dice, guessing higher/lower, and resetting the game don't seem to be working.

Here's the code for my GameController.java file:

```
package com.example.gameofchance;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameController {

    @FXML
    private Label poolLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label roll1Label;
    @FXML
    private TextField guessField;
    @FXML
    private Label resultLabel;

    private int pointPool;
    private int roll1Value;

    public void initialize() {
        // Set the initial point pool
        pointPool = 100;
        poolLabel.setText(String.valueOf(pointPool));
    }

    public void rollDice() {
        // Generate a random value for the first dice roll
        Random random = new Random();
        roll1Value = random.nextInt(6) + 1;
        roll1Label.setText(String.valueOf(roll1Value));
    }

    public void guessHigher() {
        // Check if the second dice roll is higher than the first
        int guessValue = Integer.parseInt(guessField.getText());
        int roll2Value = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (roll2Value > roll1Value) {
            resultLabel.setText("You win!");
            pointPool += guessValue;
        } else {
            resultLabel.setText("You lose!");
            pointPool -= guessValue;
        }
        // Update the point pool label
        poolLabel.setText(String.valueOf(pointPool));
    }

    public void guessLower() {
        // Check if the second dice roll is lower than the first
        int guessValue = Integer.parseInt(guessField.getText());
        int roll2Value = new Random().nextInt(6) + 1;
        if (roll2Value < roll1Value) {
            resultLabel.setText("You win!");
            pointPool += guessValue;
        } else {
            resultLabel.setText("You lose!");
            pointPool -= guessValue;
        }
        // Update the point pool label
        poolLabel.setText(String.valueOf(pointPool));
    }

    public void resetGame() {
        // Reset the point pool and clear the labels
        pointPool = 100;
        poolLabel.setText(String.valueOf(pointPool));
        roll1Label.setText("");
        guessField.setText("");
        resultLabel.setText("");
    }

}
```

And here's the code for my Game.fxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:controller="com.example.gameofchance.GameController" spacing="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <Label text="Welcome to the Game of Chance!" />
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Label text="Point/Money Pool:" />
        <Label fx:id="poolLabel" />
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Label text="Roll 1: " />
        <Label fx:id="roll1Label" />
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Label text="Guess: " />
        <TextField fx:id="guessField" />
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Button text="Higher" onAction="#guessHigher" />
        <Button text="Lower" onAction="#guessLower" />
    </HBox>
    <HBox spacing="10">
        <Button text="Roll" onAction="#rollDice" />
        <Button text="Reset" onAction="#resetGame" />
    </HBox>
    <Label fx:id="resultLabel" />
</VBox>
```

And here is my main if needed:

```
package com.example.gameofchance;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("game.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Game of Chance");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to JavaFX, so I'm not sure where to start debugging this issue. Can someone help me figure out why my buttons aren't working and how to fix it? I am also using JDK 19 and JavaFX SDK 21 (Scene Builder)

When I run the program, I can see the GUI and the labels for the point pool, the first roll, the guess, and the result all update correctly. However, clicking on any of the buttons doesn't seem to do anything.

I've tried adding debug statements to the methods in my GameController class, and it looks like the methods are getting called correctly when I click on the buttons. However, the expected behavior (updating the labels, modifying the point pool, etc.) doesn't seem to be happening.

At the end of the program, I want to have a functional game of chance that meets the requirements, most of which I already have with the buttons being the part i'm stuck on. Here are some things you can expect the program to do:

Display a GUI with labels for the current point/money pool, the value of the first roll, the user's guess, and the result of the game
Allow the user to input a bet and click a "Roll Dice" button to roll the first die and display its value
Enable the "Guess Higher" and "Guess Lower" buttons, which allow the user to guess whether the second roll will be higher or lower than the first roll
After the user has made a guess, enable a "Roll Second Dice" button that rolls the second die and displays its value
Update the GUI to display the user's guess, the result of the game (win or lose), and the updated point/money pool based on the bet and the result of the game
Disable the "Guess Higher" and "Guess Lower" buttons until the next game starts
Allow the user to reset the game and start over with a new point/money pool

PS. I only included all the other requirements because I thought it would be helpful to know what the whole program does.

Comment: I would expect an [`fx:controller`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers) attribute in your FXML file.

Comment: @trashgod, yes you are correct, I changed the code above, but it still doesn't fix the error and my new GameController is now underlined red beside where I declared the fx:controller

Comment: What package is `GameController` in? What actually happens now when you run it?

Comment: Assuming package `game`, try `fx:controller="game.GameController"`.

Comment: @James_D package ```com.example.gameofchance;```

Comment: But in the `fx:controller` attribute, you just have `com.example`.

Comment: When posting code, please don’t omit the `package` statements.  As can be seen from comments, they are important and without them there can be errors and confusion.

Comment: @James_D  Sorry, does it really, I saw it on my screen. I retyped that line so it should be there now. It's also at the top of my other files as well.

Comment: @jewelsea I thought it was in the code my mistake, I fixed it so I hope you can see it now.

Comment: The `fx:controller` needs to be the fully qualified class name (ie the class name with the full package prepended). You just have the package name. It needs to be `fx:controller = “com.example.gameofchance.GameController”`.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for that, I missed that when reviewing my code but GameController doesn't work in the class name

Comment: as @James_D already noted: you fx:controller attribute is wrong .. the solution is to fix it. If it's still not working, edit the question to include your changes (and all imports and package declarations - which also already was suggested ;)

Comment: I see a problem: as listed, the opening code fence and package declaration were on the same line, obscuring the latter. The `fx:controller` should indeed be a fully qualified classname, not just a package name, as suggested by @James_D and shown below.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [*Controller Method Event Handlers*](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controller_method_event_handlers), your `Game.fxml` file must specify its associated controller as an attribute of the root element. As you are using a package named `com.example.gameofchance`; both `Main` and `GameController` should start with this:

```
package com.example.gameofchance;
```

Your `Game.fxml` should then include this:

```
<VBox fx:controller="com.example.gameofchance.GameController" … >
```

[image: Game screenshot]

Comment: There is an error with ```<VBox fx:controller="game.GameController" spacing="10" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/21" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">``` where game.GameController is underlined. I will update the code above.

Comment: Both `Main` and `GameController` should start with your chosen package name.

Comment: Yes, I have put ```package game;``` for both, but the same error still pops up, should I use a different jdk and sdk

Comment: Using your revised code, edited to reveal your chosen package name, try `fx:controller="com.example.gameofchance.GameController"`.